# Prevent restarting Mac by accident

Tags: mac, parallels-desktop

I recently tried different keystrokes to regain control of my mouse/keyboard from parallels, and I pressed something that cause my Mac to start shutting down. It didn't prompt me to confirm that I wanted to shutdown my Mac, it just started closing applications for the shutdown.

Question is there a way to require that the use respond to a confirmation dialog before shutting down / restarting their Mac?

Additional info- I was multi-tasking at the time, setting up a Linux KVM host , a Raspberry Pi image , among other things. I almost lost all of my work so I would like to put in a safeguard against accidentally restarting my Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More than likely, you hit <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> and the <kbd>⦿ Power button</kbd> .

That's the only keyboard combination that will force restart a Mac without asking you to save unsaved documents.  The only other way to shut down a Mac without it prompting you is to hold the <kbd>⦿ Button</kbd> for 5 seconds.

> Question is there a way to require that the use respond to a confirmation dialog before shutting down / restarting their Mac?

There are key combinations that already exist with confirmations:

- <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⏏ Media Eject</kbd> - Quit all apps, then restart your Mac. If any open documents have unsaved changes, you'll be asked whether you want to save them. <sup>*</sup>
- <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>⦿ Power Button</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>⏏ Media Eject</kbd> - Quit all apps, then shut down your Mac. If any open documents have unsaved changes, you'll be asked whether you want to save them.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*</sup> Doesn't apply to keyboards that have a Touch Bar.

It's probably best that you familiarize yourself with the [keyboard shortcuts that are set by default](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201236) in macOS

Comment: Get a cat - apparently they can be good for entering various commands... :)

Comment: @SolarMike getting a cat would have the opposite effect of what OP wants :)

Comment: @jcm I know, just for a smile this morning... :)

Comment: I was pretty much a like a cat at that moment. I think Parallels tells you the keyboard "escape" sequence once after installation, and that is it. if you don't use it for months after that, you might think ctlr-opt? opt-cmd?    ctrl-opt was the combo that I was looking for to release control back to my iMac.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to prevent a restart with the fewest resources is to enable fast-user switching and open an active login session.

[image: enable fast user switching]

Switch back to your session and, in case of anything but a forced shutdown/restart will show following message:

[image: fast switching restart dialog]